# Converting an old (4.2) laravel with multiple datasources to new API based datasource for one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an older Laravel App that has 7 different databases in the app/config/database.php file, the type of databases are not even consistent 4 different types mysql, pgsql, sqlite and sqlsrv.  The SQL Server is being replaced with a JSON based API. There are 159 Controllers and 212 Models in the app (not including anything that isn't in the appropriate directories).

Although I have built several apps with newer versions of Laravel I have avoided a lot of the ORM stuff for control and readability and I am having a hard time reading some of this code and coming up with a solution to replace the SQL Server without re-writing everything.

Here is an example:

**MembershipController.php**

```
<?php
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

class MembershipsController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new membership
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create() {
        
        $products = Product::lists('title', 'id');
        $divisions = Division::lists('name', 'id');
        $this->layout = View::make('memberships.create', compact('products', 'divisions'));
        $this->layout->title = 'New Membership';

        // add breadcrumb to current page
        $this->layout->breadcrumb = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Dashboard',
                'link' => 'dashboard',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon-home',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'All Memberships',
                'link' => 'dashboard/memberships',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon-plus',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'New Membership',
                'link' => 'dashboard/memberships/create',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon-plus',
            ),

        );
    }
}
```

**Product.php** Model

```
<?php


class Product extends \Eloquent {
  protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        'division_id' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'sku' => 'required',
        'short_description' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'daily' => 'required',
        'term' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'appfee' => 'required',
        'family' => 'required'
    ];
    
public function getDateFormat() {
        return 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    }
    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    //public $timestamps = true;

     public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Option', 'product_options')->withPivot('enabled', 'price', 'id');
    }

    public function division(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Division', 'division_id');
    }

    public function msa(){

        return $this->hasOne('MSA', 'msa_version');
    }
    
}
```

I know that Laravel is *automagically* querying the SQLServer database and using the Title and Id to make a list but I am not seeing *where* the dbase call is being made so that I can "hi-jack" it to convert it to an API Call.

There are hundreds of similar calls in this app and I am trying to find the best tackle converting all of these calls that were going to sqlsrv to now go to the API.

How do I prevent the Model from using ORM instead inject a call to the API into the Model to get the data?

Any suggestions would be helpful, since I am not even certain how to begin.

Comment: What do you mean by replaced with API? are you getting data from an API?

Comment: The app is currently getting data from multiple databases. Using Eloquent and ORM. One of the databases is being replaced with an API that has dataset numbers instead of table names although the fields are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible without custom implementation like this: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

You can check these too:

- https://github.com/Indatus/trucker
- https://github.com/CristalTeam/php-api-wrapper

I'm not sure if anything of these fits to your case but it's a good start point.

Comment: I have seen all three of these packages and use the jensseger package on another project. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to put them in play in this instance as I need to prevent all ORM interaction on all of the new models since there are differences in the API such as, although the field names are the same the table names are not. In the example above the table that was "products" is now tbl3254 and the API is not RESTful, each call requires a payload indicating table and parameters.

Comment: @Lance first start with really basic implementation - just to replace Eloquent, make a class like EloquentToApi then replace "extends \Eloquent" with "extends \EloquentToApi" and implement method by method :) I'm not sure how much time you are able to spend on this but if your API is not well structured you are in trouble :) In fact you are in trouble since you've started work on project like this :)